# Beanpath.instanceOf apparently not working

Tags: hibernate, instanceof, querydsl

I am using querydsl-apt 3.2.4 and hibernate 3.5.5-Final version and the following code doesn't works for me:

```
PathBuilder<Person> person = new PathBuilder<Person>(Person.class, "person");
BooleanExpression expression = person.getString("name").eq("Alan").and(person.instanceOf(Person.class));
HibernateQuery query = new HibernateQuery(HibernateUtil.currentSession());
query.from(person).where(expression));
query.list(person.getString("name"));
```

But when I replace the value of expression for:

```
person.getString("name").eq("Alan").and(person.get("class").eq("F"));
```

Since "F" is a valid disciminator value for Person, it works perfectly getting the result I was expecting in the first blockquote. Any Idea why the first code doesn't work?

Comment: Does the first code error or does person.instanceOf(Person.class) evaluate to false when you are expecting it to be true?

Comment: it evaluates to false

Comment: @alan Could you create a ticket? https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues?state=open